# Plotting of MFCC power spectrogram Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, scipy

Can anyone help me plot a `mfcc` feature as a power spectrogram! I am only able to plot `mfcc` coefficients which is not represented in time domain. I want to plot `mfcc` feature in time domain. I also tried applying DCT to convert it into time domain!

```
from python_speech_features import mfcc
#from python_speech_features import logfbank `enter code here`
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from python_speech_features import logfbank
import scipy.fftpack

(rate,sig) = wav.read("Voice0003.wav")
mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig,rate)


(rate2,sig2) = wav.read("Voice0004.wav")
mfcc_feat2 = mfcc(sig2,rate2)
yf = scipy.fftpack.fft(sig,rate)
#fbank_feat = logfbank(yf)
#dct=scipy.fftpack.dct(fbank_feat      tried converting into Time Domain            didnt help


print(len(mfcc_feat))
print(len(mfcc_feat2))

pd.DataFrame(mfcc_feat2).T.plot()
plt.show()
pd.DataFrame(mfcc_feat).T.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: More information/context on what is wrong with your current code would help people to answer this better.

Comment: i want some proper insight on specgram function of python.

Answer (score 0):

Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(signal, NFFT=NFFT,   Fs=2,noverlap=100,         cmap=None)  #signal is 1D array of .wav file